# Uncrustify split function call parameters

Tags: c++, code-formatting, uncrustify

I want to format the code like this:

- a) line width maximum 120
- b)- function call parameters one per line with indent if the length of the function is called is > 120 else function call in one line
- c)- it the function call is inside a if, for, while, etc... the parameters should be formatted as written at **b)**

I have the code (it is just a fictive):

```
void a_function()
{
    if(verify_if_the_conditions_are_meet(first_parameter, second_parameter, third_parameter, fourth_parameter, fifth_parameter, sixth_parameter ))
    {
        call_a_function_with_many_parameters(first_parameter, second_parameter, third_parameter, fourth_parameter, fifth_parameter, sixth_parameter);       
    }

    save(first_parameter, second_parameter, third_parameter, fourth_parameter, fifth_parameter, sixth_parameter);
}
```

And now, I want to have the result:

```
void a_function()
{
    if(verify_if_the_conditions_are_meet(
        first_parameter, 
        second_parameter, 
        third_parameter, 
        fourth_parameter, 
        fifth_parameter, 
        sixth_parameter ))
    {
        call_a_function_with_many_parameters(
            first_parameter, 
            second_parameter, 
            third_parameter, 
            fourth_parameter, 
            fifth_parameter, 
            sixth_parameter);
    }

    save(first_parameter, second_parameter, third_parameter, fourth_parameter, fifth_parameter, sixth_parameter);
}
```

I've used the following options in Uncrustify 0.63:

> code_width                    = 120
>
> ls_func_split_full            = true
>
> ls_code_width                 = false
>
> nl_func_leave_one_liners  = true
>
> indent_func_call_param        = true
>
> nl_func_def_start           = add
>
> nl_func_def_start_single    = remove
>
> align_oc_msg_colon_first    = false

With this settings I get just like this:

```
void a_function()
{
    if(verify_if_the_conditions_are_meet(first_parameter, second_parameter, third_parameter, fourth_parameter, 
        fifth_parameter, sixth_parameter ))
    {
        call_a_function_with_many_parameters(
            first_parameter, 
            second_parameter, 
            third_parameter, 
            fourth_parameter, 
            fifth_parameter, 
            sixth_parameter);
    }

    save(first_parameter, second_parameter, third_parameter, fourth_parameter, fifth_parameter, sixth_parameter);
}
```

Have anyone a situation where the function call is inside a if/for/while and needs to have the parameters split like this?

Answer (score 6):

Use these settings:

```
nl_func_call_start_multi_line   = true
nl_func_call_args_multi_line    = true
code_width                      = 120
```

- `code_width`: Try to limit code width to *N* columns
- `nl_func_call_start_multi_line`: Whether to add newline after `(` in a function call if `(` and `)` are in different lines.
- `nl_func_call_args_multi_line`: Whether to add newline after each `,` in a function call if `(` and `)` are in different lines.

Optionally with:

```
nl_func_call_end_multi_line     = true
```

- `nl_func_call_end_multi_line`: Whether to add newline before `)` in a function call if `(` and `)` are in different lines.